# {C++} (Linux) "Communicate in socket through tor"

Tags: client, server

I have a question, regularly we see the use of tor in socks5 for http requests, concretely if we wanted to make a client-server communication (socket) by asking the client to go by tor to send his request to the server all In C ++, what would be the approach to adapt?

Thank you for your time and your answers!

Ps: google translation, sorry.

edit : Add source code
    #include "h/main.h"

```
using namespace std;

bool TcpSockC::_Init()
{
    // SOCKET c for tor
    c = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (c == INVALID_SOCKET) 
    {
        perror("Erreur main::sock()");
        CLOSE(c);
        return 0;
    }
    // sockaddr_in cs for tor
    cs.sin_family = AF_INET;
    cs.sin_port = htons(9050);
    inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1", &(cs.sin_addr.s_addr));
    return 1;
}
bool TcpSockC::_Co()
{

    if(connect(c, (sockaddr*)&cs, sizeof(cs)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        perror("Erreur main::connect()");
        CLOSE(c);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
bool TcpSockC::Send()
{
    struct sockaddr_in destaddr; // for socket server
    destaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("x.x.x.x");
    int dest_port = 4148;
    char buf[256], *ptr;
    ptr = buf;
    PUT_BYTE( ptr++,5);
    PUT_BYTE( ptr++,1);
    PUT_BYTE(ptr++,0x00);
    if (send(c,buf,ptr-buf,0) != -1)
        if (recv(c,buf,2,0) != -1)
            if ( buf[0] != 5 || buf[1] == 0xFF )
            {
                cout << "error" END;
                return 0;
            }
            ptr = buf;
            PUT_BYTE(ptr++,5);
            PUT_BYTE(ptr++,1);
            PUT_BYTE(ptr++,0);
            PUT_BYTE(ptr++,1);
            memcpy( ptr, &destaddr.sin_addr.s_addr,sizeof(destaddr.sin_addr));
            ptr += sizeof(destaddr.sin_addr);
            PUT_BYTE(ptr++,dest_port>>8);
            PUT_BYTE(ptr++,dest_port&0xFF);
            send(c,buf,ptr-buf,0);
            recv(c,buf,4,0);
            cout << buf[1];
            if(buf[1] != 0x00)
            {

                cout << "error" END;
                return 0;
            }
            ptr = buf + 4;
            switch ( buf[3] ) {                         
            case 1:                                     
                recv( c, ptr, 4+2,0 );              
                break;
            case 3:                                     
                recv( c, ptr, 1 ,0);                 
                recv( c, ptr+1, *(unsigned char*)ptr + 2,0);
                break;
            case 4:                                    
                recv( c, ptr, 16+2,0 );              
                break;
            }
            printf("Succes!");

            // There we are connected to the server x.x.x.x through the proxy
            // Sample Send
            char req[] = "Hello World";
            send(c, req, sizeof(req), 0);
            CLOSE(c);
            return 1;
}
int main()
{
    TcpSockC c;
    c._Init();
    c._Co();
    c.Send();
    return 0;
}
```

After authentication how to send a command to the server through tor?
Thanks.

Edit : Solution found updated source code, thanks Alexey Vesnin for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use tor as a socks proxy **with dns resolution via proxy**, and it will be fine: Tor works on OSI layers 3 and 4(TCP) and it basically tunnels TCP pipes, it does not care if it's a http or other protocol inside

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying.
Would you have code examples?

Comment: Just use [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html) it has a very detailed tutorial and examples :)

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying, i prefer not to use dependency.

Comment: you mean the native C code?

Comment: Thank you replying, No, cURL asks to link libcurl.lib and I would like to avoid linking this lib.

Comment: if you're not using dependency then you're writing all the functions on your own. cURL is quite common around for 10+ years, so it's not something unusual. Do you need a native(without any external libraries) code sample or you need a copy-and-paste example that can use an external library? What is your platform, by the way? I used to use cURL even in kernel-less ARM firmwares - it worked OK

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am under linux, but it can be deported under windows if the envy took me, I added the code souce of my program and thus clarified the matter, awaiting your return: )

Edit : Translation is good? I trust google ..

Comment: cURL works fine under Windows: checked myself in Cygwin, cygwin64, Mingw32, mingw64, Visual Studio . I'll take a look at your code and post a little later, ok? And you have already a potential problem: address is as IP, but it has to be resolved from SOCKS proxy. If you're connecting to pre-defined IP address it's ok

Comment: Here it is: http://www.xoriant.com/blog/software-product-development/socks5-proxy-client-in-c.html

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response, I had a problem linking cURL under Windows (problem of link with the .lib) even if it is my fault, I avoided it. Yes no worries thank you for your time. I will use gethostbyname later for the moment the ip is predefined.

Comment: So implement SOCKS5. It's standardized and trivial. https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt

Comment: f I understand correctly, I am connected to my server by the proxy tor, so I just send a simple send () command to go through the proxy to the defined host?
Example: send (sock, "helloworld", 11,0)

Is that correct?

Comment: gethostbyname will leak your data through system-default resolver - you need to resolve ALL the stuff via proxy

Comment: yes you will - after the OK-response from proxy - you'll have a "sock to your desired destination", just use it as a direc one

Comment: Good ! Thank you for guiding me!
However, how to resolve from the proxy?
Thank you again for your time.

Comment: as it said [in RFC1928](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt) ATYP='03' and you're putting not IP but a domain name. It will resolve it itself on a proxy side

Comment: Ok so it will solve a domain like example.com and still accept an ipv4 address it just will not need to solve it? I ask in case there are subtleties :)
 
Thank you replying

Comment: you're putting a domain name instead of IP and it is automatically resolved - you don't even have to get the IP from proxy, all is done in one transaction - you will have a socket to your destination the very same way. The difference is that the domain name will be seamlessly resolved on a proxy side before opening a socket. Tor uses this step to make a connection to the other side(your server)

Comment: Thank you for your answers that have been very informative!

Comment: My pleasure! I'm glad that it helped you! Feel free to ask further questions

Answer (score 0):

Ye Gods! That is some ugly looking C++ code!

But to address the question, the SOCKS negotiation *is* the "command".

You connect to Tor's SOCKS port and say "Tor, connect to this destination!" and Tor replies "Yay" or "Nay". If it's "Nay", figure out what went wrong or try again, if it's "Yay" then the socket that you negotiated the SOCKS protocol with now sends to, and receives from, your requested destination.

So, where `// Send cmd to server through tor?` is, currently is where you'd send whatever data you wanted to send to the remote server in the first place through your existing connection.

e.g.

```
char cmd[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n";
send(c, cmd, sizeof(cmd), 0); // send HTTP reqest
recv(c, buf, sizeof(buf), 0); // buf now contains the http response, or some of it at least
```

Once you've successfully negotiated the SOCKS protocol with Tor's SOCKS port you should consider the socket that you negotiated the SOCKS connection with as being like a normal socket to your requested destination.

*P.S. I wrote a simple SOCKS5 implementation intended for use with Tor from C, available [here](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/SOCKS). See `socks.h` for usage.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have been seeing your code, it is interesting, it is very well presented. Unfortunately I do not fully understand it, and I do not like to use what I do not understand. But I think using two three things your code thank you for sharing and your time!